# Problem with Docker plugin for Java (fabric8io)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker

After executing `docker:build` I get this error

> [ERROR] DOCKER> Unable to build image [dmarquina/watered-plant] :
>   Dockerfile parse error line 5: unknown instruction:
>   /USERS/DMARQUINA/APPLICATION/WATERED-PLANT.JAR (Bad Request: 400)

Comment: Hello, could you share your fabric8io configuration and your Dockerfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

avoid using format in pom, just write the full name in `Entrypoint`